# How to handle state on array of checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to handle the checked state of an array of checkboxes?

I have this array:

```
const CheckboxItems = t => [
  {
    checked: true,
    value: 'itemsCancelled',
    id: 'checkBoxItemsCancelled',
    labelText: t('cancellations.checkBoxItemsCancelled'),
  },
  {
    checked: true,
    value: 'requestDate',
    id: 'checkboxRequestDate',
    labelText: t('cancellations.checkboxRequestDate'),
  },
  {
    checked: true,
    value: 'status',
    id: 'checkboxStatus',
    labelText: t('cancellations.checkboxStatus'),
  },
  {
    checked: true,
    value: 'requestedBy',
    id: 'checkboxRequestedBy',
    labelText: t('cancellations.checkboxRequestedBy'),
  },
];
```

And I am using it here:

```
class TableToolbarComp extends React.Component {
    state = {
        isChecked: true,
    };

    onChange = (value, id, event) => {       
      this.setState(({ isChecked }) => ({ isChecked: !isChecked }));
    };


    render() {
      const { isChecked } = this.state;
      return (
        {CheckboxItems(t).map(item => (
          <ToolbarOption key={item.id}>
            <Checkbox
              id={item.id}
              labelText={item.labelText}
              value={item.value}
              checked={isChecked}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
          </ToolbarOption>
        ))}

      )
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that every time I unchecked one, the rest of them get unchecked too. I need to manage the state separately to send some information to other components through a redux action.

EDIT:

[This is the UI library I am using](http://react.carbondesignsystem.com/?selectedKind=Checkbox&selectedStory=checked&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Fstories%2Fstories-panel)

Comment: Are you using some library that provides that `Checkbox` component? Semantic UI, Bootstrap / Material Design, ...?

Comment: Hi @T.J.Crowder this is what I am usiing: http://react.carbondesignsystem.com/?selectedKind=Checkbox&selectedStory=checked&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Fstories%2Fstories-panel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the *container's* `isChecked` as the state for all of your checkboxes, using a method on your container to flip that one flag that it applies to all of them (`isChecked`).

Instead, either:

1. Give the checkboxes themselves state, rather than making them simple objects, or
2. Maintain a state map in the container keyed by the checkbox item (or perhaps its name)

I would lean toward #1, which I **think** would look like this with that library:

```
class TableToolbarComp extends React.Component {
    state = {
        items: CheckboxItems(t) // Your code seems to have a global called `t`
    };

    onChange = (value, id, event) => {       
        this.setState(({ items }) => {
          // Copy the array
          items = items.slice();
          // Find the matching item
          const item = items.find(i => i.id === id);
          if (item) {
              // Update its flag and set state
              item.checked = !item.checked;
              return { items };
          }
        });
    };

    render() {
      const { items } = this.state;
      return (
        {items.map(item => (
          <ToolbarOption key={item.id}>
            <Checkbox
              id={item.id}
              labelText={item.labelText}
              value={item.value}
              checked={item.checked}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
          </ToolbarOption>
        ))}

      )
    }
}
```

Changes:

- Call `CheckboxItems` **once**, keep the result as state.
- In `onChange`, find the relevant checkbox by `id` (the lib passes the `id`) and flip its `checked` flag
- In `render`, get the `items` from state and for each item, use its `checked` flag, not your `isChecked (which I've removed entirely

Comment: Can you provide a brief code sample about how to do the 1st thing you mentioned above? Please. And this is the library I am using: http://react.carbondesignsystem.com/?selectedKind=Checkbox&selectedStory=checked&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Fstories%2Fstories-panel

Comment: @TheUnnamed - I ***think*** (don't take my word for it, I've never seen that lib before and just spent a few minutes reading from your comment on the question) that with that library, you can't store the state on the checkbox itself and you'd either have to use a wrapper component to do #1 or do #2 instead. I wouldn't want to try to code something up without knowing more about the library, but I'm pretty sure those are your options (wrapper component or state map).

Comment: @TheUnnamed - But I took a stab at it. :-)