# How to add styles to individual elements in react using e.target, when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to add styles to the inidividual elements. I want when an individual div( is clicked to make sure that the paragraph of the specific  changes from display: none to dislay:block. But the problem is, when I click only on one , all the paragraph text is displayed.
here is the css below:

```
.cards{
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 20vh;
}

[class*=cardDisplay]{
    height: 80%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 200px;
    background: black; 
    color: white;
    margin: auto;
}

[class*=card-content]{
    display: none;
}

[class*=card-content-2]{
    display: block;
}
```

and the react.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import {useState} from "react";
import "./game.css";

function Game() {
    const [styling, setStyling] = useState("card-content")

    const handleClick = () => {
        setStyling("card-content-2")
    }

  return (
      <div className="cards">
          <div className="cardDisplay card-1" onClick={handleClick}>
              <p className={styling}>Win</p>
          </div>
          <div className="cardDisplay card-2" onClick={handleClick}>
              <p className={styling}>Sorry, No Win</p>
          </div>
          <div className="cardDisplay card-3" >
              <p className={styling} onClick={handleClick}>Sorry, No Win</p>
          </div>
      </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Something about my answer felt familiar, and sure enough, it's very much like my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53712001/how-to-handle-state-on-array-of-checkboxes). Possible duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

You're using only **one** `styling` that you're applying to all paragraphs. If you want distinct styling for each paragraph, you have to hold that state separately for each paragraph.

Either:

1. Make the `div`+`paragraph` a component that holds its own state, or
2. Have multiple `styling` state members (perhaps an array).

I would lean toward the first:

```
function Card({className = "", children}) {
    const [styling, setStyling] = useState("card-content");

    const handleClick = () => {
        setStyling("card-content-2")
    };

    return (
        <div className={`cardDisplay ${className}`} onClick={handleClick}>
            <p className={styling}>{children}</p>
        </div>
    );
};

function Game() {
    return (
        <div className="cards">
            <Card className="card-1">Win</Card>
            <Card className="card-2">Sorry, No Win</Card>
            <Card className="card-3">Sorry, No Win</Card>
        </div>
    );
}
```

There's lots of ways to spin that, but that's the basic idea.

But there's also an argument for the cards being an array of objects with state; here's an example with the results randomized when the component is first mounted:

```
function makeCards() {
    const num = 3;
    const win = Math.floor(Math.random() * num);
    return Array.from({length: 3}, (_, index) => ({
        id: `card-${index}`,
        result: index === win ? "Win" : "Sorry, No Win",
        showing: false,
    }));
}

function Game() {
    const [cards, setCards] = useState(makeCards);
    const handleClick = (event) => {
        const id = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-id");
        setCards(prevCards => {
            const newCards = prevCards.map(card => {
                if (card.id === id) {
                    return {...card, showing: true};
                }
                return card;
            });
            return newCards;
        });
    };
    return (
        <div className="cards">
            {cards.map(({id, result, showing}) => (
                <div key={id} data-id={id} className={`cardDisplay ${id}`} onClick={handleClick}>
                    <p className={showing ? "card-content" : "card-content-2"}>{result}</p>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I'm new to development. I now know the power that lies behind stack overflow. I decided to go ahead with the first solution. But i kind of altered it abit. I don't know if i should send you a snippet of my code, but...

Answer (score 0):

This may help you. It really works........

```
import React from 'react';
import {useState} from "react";
import "./game.css";

function Game() {
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.target.firstChild?.classList?.remove("card-content");
    e.target.firstChild?.classList?.add("card-content-2");
  };

  return (
    <div className="cards">
      <div className="cardDisplay card-1" onClick={handleClick}>
        <p className="card-content">Win</p>
      </div>
      <div className="cardDisplay card-2" onClick={handleClick}>
        <p className="card-content">Sorry, No Win</p>
      </div>
      <div className="cardDisplay card-3" onClick={handleClick}>
        <p className="card-content">Sorry, No Win</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot man. I tried going with the e.target option before, but nothing seemed to work in my favor. But i see where i went wrong. This is actually the definition of "minimise the use of state wherever you can"

Comment: Rather than just a code snippet, can you add some context on WHY/HOW it works?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

What you are currently doing is changing the *styling* for each of the **p tags**.

I will advise you have a custom class that returns your **div tag that contains the p tag**

Have an array of Objects that contain the **card style** and the **text** that will be displayed. Map through the array and return the style and tags accordingly. As displayed below.

handle the click events in the custom div.

```
import React from 'react';
import "./game.css";
import MyDiv from './MyDiv';


const cards = [{ cardStyle: 'card-1', text: "Win" },
{ cardStyle: 'card-2', text: 'Sorry, No Win' },
{ cardStyle: 'card-3', text: 'Sorry, NoWin' }];


function Game() {
    return (
        <div className="cards">

            {cards.map((card, index) =>
            (<MyDiv cardNumberStyle={card.cardStyle}
                key={index}
               
                textToDisplay={card.text} />))
            }
        </div>
    );
}





export default Game;
```

And then MyDiv is:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const MyDiv = ({ cardNumberStyle, textToDisplay }) => {
    const [styling, setStyling] = useState('card-content');

    ///Handles clicks
    const handleClick = () => {
        //conditionally change the styling
        if (styling === 'card-content')
            setStyling('card-content-2')
        else setStyling('card-content');

    }

    return (
        <div className={`cardDisplay ${cardNumberStyle}`} onClick={handleClick}>
            <p className={styling}>{textToDisplay}</p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default MyDiv;
```